# File redirection not working in shell script for aws cli output

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-ec2, sh, aws-cli

I'm creating ec2 instances and would like to get the user_data for each instance using the command:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --instance-id i-xxxx --attribute userData --output text --query "UserData.Value" | base64 --decode > file.txt
```

When running this directly via terminal it works, I'm able to get the userData printed into file.txt. However, I need this to run in a shell script I have, which gets the instance id as a parameter.

The lines in test.sh are the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --instance-id $1 --attribute userData --output text --query "UserData.Value" | base64 --decode)" > file.txt
```

Where $1 is the instance-id. When running:

```
./test.sh i-xxxxxxx
```

It creates an empty file.txt. I have changed the line in the script to:

```
echo "$(aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --instance-id $1 --attribute userData --output text --query "UserData.Value" | base64 --decode)"
```

and it prints the userData to stdout. So why it is not working for file redirection?

Thank you,

Comment: when running the script it also prints the error  "does not existd (InvalidInstanceID.NotFound) when calling the DescribeInstanceAttribute operation: The instance ID 'i-xxxxxx'", however the instance does exists and this command works outside of the shell script....

Comment: I have executed the same script of yours and everything works. Can you try to give region in the script as well? After `--query "UserData.Value"` put `--region $your region`

Comment: It's not the immediate problem here, but don't use `echo "$(somecommand)"`, just run `somecommand` directly; the `echo` and `$( )` mostly cancel each other out (except for adding the possibility of parsing confusion in between). [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point this (along with many other common mistakes). As for the actual problem: add `set -x` as the second line of the script to get an execution trace, and see what's different from what you expect to run.

Comment: Thank you @GordonDavisson! set -x and shellcheck.net were really helpful and helped me solved this. Apparently the file in which the instance ids are taken from had specials characters ^M at the end of the id so this caused issues when running the aws cli command. I have also change the echo $(cmd) to cmd